# Is there a limit to the number of files that can be added with cache.addAll?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a cache first Progressive Web App. When I add files to the cache  with cache.addAll it stops loading at 50 files. I am passing an array of 150 urls and only 50 files get transferred to the cache (in alphabetical order). I've tried using as little as 60 files with the same result. Total File size of all files is 1.4Mb and the files are all .txt files. This happens on all Desktop browsers I have tested (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and iOS). When I take the app offline any of the 50 files it cached are available. I'm getting no errors in the console. Am I hitting some kind of file limit, or is there any way to troubleshoot this?